# Applying ensambled train models on test data vs ensambling test predictions

Tags: linear-model, bootstrap, ensemble-learning

Consider we are fitting linear model to solve classification/regression problem on the given train data. What would be a better strategy to follow from the below mentioned ones to evaluate the model performance on the test data and why?

(a) Fitting *k* bootstrapped train models, getting an ensemble of *k* models then applying the final ensemble model on the entire test data.

(b) Fitting *k* bootstrapped train models and applying each of them on entire test data and getting ensemble of the predictions.